# When programming for Android, how can I get a list of almost every English word?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I'm programming something for the Android phone, and I need to have a list of as many English words as possible in the code.  I question the practicality of going through a dictiionary in real life and punching in the words manually, but when I try to Google for another solution, I really don't see much coming up.  How might I be able to get a dictionary in my code (just the words, not definitions)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search led me to [this](http://www.ibiblio.org/webster/#the_text_files). Download the XML-files, parse and add each word to a SQLite database and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an American wordlist that you can parse into Android

ftp://ftp.ox.ac.uk/pub/wordlists/american/

Here is another nice resource:

http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for an extract of a [text corpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus), such as this: [Word frequency lists and dictionary](http://www.wordfrequency.info/) from the Corpus of Contemporary American English